# Android Service onBind -> onStart

Tags: android, binding, service

I have a comprehension question about Android Services. I have a Service that performs background http operations and a Activity that should display the current state of these http operations.

So I implementet the Binder interface and so on. I can call the bindService method and onServiceConnected of my ServiceConnnection is getting called. But as far as I know, onBind doesn't calls onStartCommand() and so onStart() of the Service is never called.

So how can I call the onStart() method of the service class and start my operations. Or how is the best way to start my operations in the service, when I also want a binding between the Activity and the Service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But as far as I know, onBind doesn't
>   calls onStartCommand() and so
>   onStart() of the Service is never
>   called.

Correct.

> So how can I call the onStart() method
>   of the service class and start my
>   operations.

Call `startService()` instead of `bindService()`. Or, don't use `onStart()` to "start [your] operations" and have your bound client call some other method on the service's exposed API to do that work.

Comment: The latter one is what I do right now. The operations are now started by a method of the binder object. Is that "good" design or are there better solutions?

thx anyway.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. If the HTTP operation should go through even in the background, it's not safe to use bound service. As a bound service will be destroyed when the last client unbinds - and you would leak context if you don't unbind the service when Activity is put in the background.
So if you want the HTTP call to survive a phone call, than you should both call bind and start from your Activity.